# Swift: How to run a timer in background with HealthKit (Background Session)?

Tags: ios, swift, timer, background, healthkit

How can I initialize a simple HK session just to be able to have a timer run in background (to play haptic feedback and sound)?

I know that I have to import HeakthKit, but how do I start a simple session without anything fancy (no workout should be recorded, nothing else) so that I can have my timer run in background?